# Can you explain the rare uses of preposition 'for' here?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Some different sentences use *for* in a manner distinct from the usual:

> 1. I was **in for** a rude shock in college.
> 2. You are good at it **for a girl**.
> 3. She does it **because for** you.

The 3rd seems to be a bit weird.

Also, there are some sentences which seem to be missing the preposition *for* ,

> 4. Draw (for) me some money.

The 'draw' refers to the painting.

Comment: Draw refers to painting ?

Comment: #3 is ungrammatical.

Comment: #3 should be either because _of_, or without _because_ entirely.

Comment: #4 has to do with di-transitive verbs, and the placement of direct and indirect objects.

Comment: Anubhav, where from did you get these sentences? Does that source say these are rare uses of preposition *for*? I'm asking because I want to know. Last time, if I remember correctly, I think you told you were reading SP Bakshi, right? Just curious to know if this topic is from that book too, or from similar book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example 1: *In for* is an idiom, which functions as a predicative adjective that takes an object. It means "expected to receive" - the thing to be received is usually unwelcome, but not always.

Example 2: This is the OED's meaning 27 for 'for': " 27. In proportion to, considering; considering the nature or capacity of; considering what he, she, or it is, or that he, etc. is so and so." It gives an example from 1753: " A man of an excellent character for a Lawyer."

Example 3: This is deviant. I know of no variety of English in which this is grammatical.

Example 4: This is a standard pattern for ditransitive verbs: the indirect object may *either* come after the direct object, with a preposition:

> Draw some money for me.

or precede the direct object without a preposition:

> Draw me some money.

The typical indirect object has preposition "to", but examples with "for" are very common. In fact, as in this case, a "for" phrase can be added to many predicates with benefactive sense, and this pattern is then available:

> He baked a cake.
>
> He baked a cake for me.
>
> He baked me a cake.

Comment: In 'precede the direct object without a preposition:', why not a 'for' is required?Which rule?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh read more about ditransitive and monotransitive verb.